# How to view the output of history from a non-interactive shell given path to HISTFILE?

Tags: bash, emacs, sh, command-history

In emacs I would like to use `shell-command-to-string` to essentially retrieve something like `history | tail -n5`. Issue is that `history` is a bash built in (in interactive mode only?) so that does not work. As I am merely interested in a read-only snap of the decorated output, is there a way to parse the content of the history file (suppose it is `~/.bash_history`) and output it with the line number and date as the `history` bash command does it?

In other words, is there a way to do something like:

`(shell-command-to-string "history --pretty-dump-to-stdout-with-date-time-linenum --filename  ~/.bash_history")`

? (Or, perhaps, a different workaround?)

Comment: If the shell is not interactive, you have to turn history on: `set -o history`. If you also want history substitution to work, you can enable it with `set -H`, but IMO  this is somewhat pointless in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make `history` command output something

I expect `set -o history` to fail as it will use the history file `$HISTFILE` which most likely is unset for non-interactive shells. Assuming the history is stored in `~/.bash_history` you could execute ...

```
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history | tail -n5
```

However, this would modify your history by adding `history | tail -n5`. A better approach is to read the history file without enabling the history:

```
history -r ~/.bash_history; history | tail -n5
```

#### Commands from your current session

Assume you are inside a interactive terminal session and execute ...

```
$ myCommand
$ emacs # and inside emacs the shell command `history` as shown above
```

... then you most likely won't see `myCommand` in the history. This is because bash only writes the history to your history file when closing the session. You can manually update the history file using `history -a`, thus the following should work:

```
$ myCommand
$ history -a
$ emacs # and inside emacs the shell command `history` as shown above
```

Since most people usually would forget the `history -a` it would be best to automate this step in your `.bashrc`, either at each prompt (`PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a`), or only for emacs (`emacs() { history -a; command emacs "$@"; }`).

#### Pretty Printing

> is there a way to do something like [...] `--pretty-dump-to-stdout-with-date-time-linenum`

The history format of the `history` command is controlled by `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. The format has to be set and exported before calling `history` inside `emacs`.

Comment: Socowi, Thank you that works! I ended up drafting this entire command from within emacs: `HISTFILE=/path/to/histfile; HISTTIMEFORMAT='%Y%m%d %T '; history -r $HISTFILE; history | tail -n5`

The only disadvantage is that it redefines HISTTIMEFORMAT but I suppose the advantage of that is control in the emacs package for which offset will contain the actual command :)