# How to run a built in shell command using golang

Tags: shell, go

I am trying to run a built in shell command in golang and get the result.
Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main(){
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "history")
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(stdout))
}
```

However i just get the output:

```
exit status 127
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is the correct way to run a builtin shell command. The program works as expected [on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/BQI1GNWz7Wr). Print stderr determine the cause of the problem in your environment. This [example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0njvGSFW1cv) shows one way to print stderr.

Comment: Does your `sh` *have* a `history` command? The deleted chatgpt answer suggested using `bash`, which might actually be the right answer for the wrong reasons (assuming you use it as your main interactive shell)

Comment: @Shawn When I use bash instead of sh I get no result.

Comment: @lool The empty output is expected.  If your actual goal is to get the shell history, then update the question to state that goal.

Answer (score 3):

`"bash", "-c"` creates a bash that is non-interactive and its next commands will run assuming non-interactive. And according to my researches history is not enabled for non-interactive shells. That is why `history` command alone outputs nothing with `"bash", "-c", "history"`
The workaround that I found:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main(){
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "history -r ~/.bash_history; history")
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(stdout))
}
```

Maybe you need replace the `bash` and `~/.bash_history` with corresponding values that is related with another shell, if you are using another shell. I don't know :/

**Details:**
[How to view the output of history from a non-interactive shell given path to HISTFILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62295028/how-to-view-the-output-of-history-from-a-non-interactive-shell-given-path-to-his)
[bash -c and noninteractive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277130/bash-c-and-noninteractive-shell)
[Why does the history command do nothing in a script file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127551/why-does-the-history-command-do-nothing-in-a-script-file)

If my given any information is wrong please notify me. I have made this answer according to the sites that I posted under `Details`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `sh -c history` doesn't work. The shell you're launching doesn't have that command. `history` is not a standard POSIX command.

You might be on a system where `/bin/sh` happens to be Dash.

If `sh` happens to be Bash, the `history` command will successfully execute, even if Bash is invoked as `sh`; Bash doesn't hide that command in POSIX mode.

On a system I have here:

```
$ sh -c history
sh: 1: history: not found
$ dash -c history
dash: 1: history: not found
$ bash -c history
$ bash --posix -c history
$ bash --posix -c history
$ ln -sf /bin/bash ./sh
$ ./sh -c history
$ rm sh
```